# Log axis in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

When I add the `log ticks with fixed point` option, `pgfplots` ignores the x-axis range instead of just affecting the y-axis.

without `log ticks with fixed point`

[image]

with `log ticks with fixed point`

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{width = 3in, compat = 1.6}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}[log ticks with fixed point]
        [
            scale only axis,
            xmin=0.4, xmax=2.1,
            ymin=1e-4, ymax=0.1,
        ]
        \addplot {x^3/1e3};
    \end{semilogyaxis}        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My goal is to make a plot with y axis in ppm (parts per million). I want to avoid multiplying all the values in the table by 1e6 instead just want to change the labels by multiplying them by 1e6. How can I do this?
Right now I am manually changing the tick marks to get right display. I do this by adding `ytickten={-4,-3,-2,-1}, yticklabels={100, 1000, 10000, 100000}`. How can I make this automatic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to merge the options into ONE option list:

```
\begin{semilogyaxis}
    [
        log ticks with fixed point,
        scale only axis,
        xmin=0.4, xmax=2.1,
        ymin=1e-4, ymax=0.1,
    ]
```

in your example, the second option list is ignored and produces warnings in your `.log` file.

Comment: thank you, it was silly of me to not realize that. any suggestions on second part of the question for changing the y tick labels?

Comment: Hmm. Take a look at the `units` library which is shipped with pgfplots. If that is not what you want, you should  take a look at section "Tick Scaling - Common Factors In Ticks" in the pgfplots manual. I suppose that might be what you want here.